# Best GIS georeferencing software which automates the placing of passpoints

Tags: gis

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.3 in order to georeference infrared aerial photos. I have about 1500 photos to georeference and am certainly not relishing the thought. ArcGIS can automatically place pass-points during georeferencing but for my purpose, this is not working well. I am georeferencing infrared aerial photos using non-infrared photos as a reference. ArcGIS can not seem to recognize similarities between non-infrared and infrared and cannot run the tool.

Does anyone know of any alternatives which can accomplish this? I can supply an infrared image to test if necessary.

Comment: Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information , then edit your question and click "reopen". Thanks! :-)

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Maybe. Do your ir photos contain the location, altitude, and pitch-roll-yaw of the camera. Do you have the camera sensor size and the camera focal length? If so, send me a few photo and I will try. https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ERDAS or ENVI ? I worked on them in the past and they worked very well and ArcGIS isn't very good with the georeferenced toolbar.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178412/merging-georeferenced-images-that-have-overlapping-information/178421#178421

If this isn't what you looking for, I don't know what a better alternative program that will allow you to do georeferenced infrared photos.